# I want to upload my current VS Code settings to sync, without inheriting old settings

Tags: database, visual-studio-code, inheritance, synchronization, gmail

How can I ensure that my current Visual Studio Code settings are uploaded to synchronization without retaining any previous configurations? Additionally, I would like to know how to delete the old synchronized data and replace it with the new data while keeping the same Gmail account associated with it. Your guidance in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

I attempted to upload my current Visual Studio Code settings for synchronization, hoping to avoid inheriting any old settings. Furthermore, I sought to learn how to delete the previous synchronized data and replace it with the updated information while retaining the same Gmail account for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Gmail integration with syncing VScode settings. The best option you are looking for is using github. You can also use [Setting Sync](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-sync-vs-code-settings-between-multiple-devices-and-environments/) extension.